# Why is / my "most popular" page? What does that mean?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to Google Analytics, but I can't seem to find anything about this anywhere. On my dashboard, under "What pages do your users visit" the page "/" is listed as the most common. What does this mean? It's nearly 250 more "visited" than the next closest, which is a post.

The site is hosted through Wordpress, and I've used the Yoast plugin for a fair amount of SEO.

Answer (score 0):

"/" is the page that you get when you just navigate to your website's name (e.g. `www.example.com/`). Your website will usually just return your `index.html` but can technically be whatever you want depending on how you set up your web server.